# OpenGL Shader language initializing error cannot conver from a GLChar to a const

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm having issues passing parameters into one of my function Void ShaderCode() to be more specific, I'm getting this error:

> <sup>Error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'GLchar' to 'const
>   GLchar *'
>  1>          Conversion from integral type to pointer
>   type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast</sup>

For more insight here is my header file:

```
typedef unsigned long Molong;
void CompileFunction();
GLchar ShaderCodeStorage(const char* FilePath);
void ShaderCode(const GLuint &ShaderHandler,  char* FilePath);
void CompileShader(const GLuint &ShaderHandler, const char* Response);
Molong getFileLength(std::ifstream& file);
```

And here is my CPP

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "glm/gtx/transform2.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/type_precision.hpp"
#include "glew/glew.h"
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include "glut.h"
#include "Storage.h"

using namespace std;

void CompileFunction()
{

    GLuint MyFirstVertShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    if (0 == MyFirstVertShader)
    {
        std::cout << "There was an error making the shader" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }


     ShaderCode (MyFirstVertShader, "BasicVert.shader");

//  glShaderSource(MyFirstVertShader, 1, CodeArray, NULL);


        glCompileShader(MyFirstVertShader);

}

void ShaderCode(const GLuint &ShaderHandler,  char* FilePath)
{
    const GLchar *ShaderArray = ShaderCodeStorage(FilePath);
    glShaderSource(ShaderHandler, 1, &ShaderArray, NULL);

}


GLchar ShaderCodeStorage(const char* FilePath)
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(FilePath, ios::in);
    unsigned long Filelength = getFileLength(infile);
    GLchar *ShaderCode = new char[Filelength + 1];
    ShaderCode[Filelength] = 0;
}


Molong getFileLength(ifstream& file) {
    if (!file.good()) return 0;
    file.seekg(0, ios::end);
    unsigned long Filelength = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    return Filelength;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following function is the culprit: (There are atleast 2 problems)

```
GLchar *ShaderCodeStorage(const char* FilePath)
// 1 Return type should be GLChar *
{
    ...
    ShaderCode[Filelength] = 0;
    return ShaderCode; // 2. add return
}
```

Also where are you reading the contents of shader file? Ensure to populate the file contents.

Comment: I haven't quite got that far, I was working through some resources I have. However you've just solved my problem! I'll approve the answer when the accept cool down expires . Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mosesflava I am glad that the answer helped you :) Also make sure to `delete` the memory that you allocated using `new`